# GROUP_CONCAT empty strings with comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table with 2 columns (with some empty strings)

```
column1 column2
          A1
          B2
   C      C1
   D
   E      E1
```

if i use GROUP_CONCAT(column1), output is:

```
C,D,E
```

But i want

```
, , C, D, E
```

Because in my PHP file i use explode() for convert string in array.
if i use GROUP_CONCAT(column2), output is correct:

```
A1, B2, C1, , E1
```

Any ideas?

EDIT- Maybe I understood the mistake. I use a DISTINCT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(column1))
```

So, if i have 2 empty strings, they become one and the output is often with only one " ,". Somone know how to delete DISTINCT only for empty strings?

Comment: Are you sure it’s empty string and not nulls?

Comment: Also, I'm rather suspicious that you're doing this to multiple columns - it suggests the data is being displayed in a table of some sort, and thus should have been left as rows to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I'm not very experienced with SQL. 
yes, they are empty strings and not nulls

Comment: And i haven't null values in my table. Only strings or empty strings

Comment: Maybe I understood the mistake. I use a DISTINCT. So, if i have 2 empty strings, they become one and the output is often with only one " ,". Somone know how to set DISTINCT for empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `NULL` values.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores them.  So, replace them:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(column1, ' '))
```

Actually, your output looks more like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(column1, '') SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: The problem is that there aren't null values, but there are empty strings